# How does React Router recursively create pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm talking about this example here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const PEEPS = [
  { id: 0, name: "Michelle", friends: [1, 2, 3] },
  { id: 1, name: "Sean", friends: [0, 3] },
  { id: 2, name: "Kim", friends: [0, 1, 3] },
  { id: 3, name: "David", friends: [1, 2] }
];

function find(id) {
  return PEEPS.find(p => p.id == id);
}

function RecursiveExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Person match={{ params: { id: 0 }, url: "" }} />
    </Router>
  );
}

function Person({ match }) {
  let person = find(match.params.id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        {person.name}
        ’s Friends
      </h3>
      <ul>
        {person.friends.map(id => (
          <li key={id}>
            <Link to={`${match.url}/${id}`}>{find(id).name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Route path={`${match.url}/:id`} component={Person} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default RecursiveExample;
```

In this example, I understand how the recursion works one step at a time. What confuses me, is when (in that mini browser) if I were to put this link in directly after refreshing the page, `/1/0/3/2/3/2`, or any other nested example, how does React Router know to render the components in that right order. There is no explicit Route path with match + `/:id1/:id2/:id3` etc.

I know that isn't feasible because it can go till infinity, but how is React Router able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** The main trick here is that the `Person` component holding the `Route` renders itself each time as long as the `path` of the rendered `Route` matches the URL.

---

**Details**

By design, the component passed into a Route's `component` prop is rendered only when Route's `path` prop matches the URL of the page.

```
{/* Something will get rendered when the URL /whatever matches the URL of the page */}
<Route path="/whatever" component={Something}>
```

Since we only render a nested `Person` (with its own `Route`) on click, we can keep generating these recursive routes indefinitely.

Each time a `Person` is rendered, it renders a `Route` within it as sort of a placeholder for the next `Person`.

```
function Person({ match }) {
  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      {/* this route is a placeholder for the next Person */}
      <Route path={`${match.url}/:id`} component={Person} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This next `Person` gets rendered if its owning `Route`'s `path` matches the URL. The owning `Route`'s `path` is the URL of the parent plus another id, i.e. `match.url + '/:id'`.

This is how we get recursive rendering. `Person` renders a `Route` which renders a `Person` which renders a `Route`... this repeats until the last rendered `Route`'s `path` doesn't match the page URL.

*Note: [`match` prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) is passed in by `Route` into the component passed as the `component` prop into that `Route`. This is how `Person` has access to it.*

One thing to note: the application always starts with `Michelle`'s friends (i.e. the friends of the person with `id` being `0`) because of:

```
function RecursiveExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      {/* This part of the code passes in a fake `match` prop to always start of the app from Michelle's point of view */}
      <Person match={{ params: { id: 0 }, url: "" }} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This means that no matter if you first open the page or refresh the page at `/0/1/2`, React Router always renders `Michelle` as the first `Person` which will render a nested `<Route path='/:id' component={Person} />`.

This means that the initial state of the app always looks like:

```
<RecursiveExample>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Person>
      <Route path="/:id" />
    </Person>
  </BrowserRouter>
</RecursiveExample>
```

Which renders as:

[image: app always starts with friends of Michelle]

If the application was loaded at `/`, the rendering stops at the above state until we start interacting with the app.

If however, we refreshed the page at `/0/1/2`, the rendering will continue. After initial state shown above is rendered, React Router will find out that `path` from `<Route path="/:id" />` matches the `/0/1/2` URL (by taking the `0` ignoring the rest), fill up the `id` as `0` and render the next `Person` (the one with `id` as `0`).

*Note: above URL matching works because the default matching strategy of a `Route` is to ignore any extra characters at the end of the path. This is why `/:id` matches `/0/1/2`, the `id` is `0` and the `/1/2` part is ignored. We could use the [`exact` prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) to force the match to be, well, exact, but this would then break the recursive behavior, i.e. `/:id` would only match `/0` but not `/0/1/2`.*

At this point our tree looks like:

```
<RecursiveExample>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Person>
      <Route path="/:id" {/* this matches /0 */}
        <Person>
          {/* we're here during the rendering stage */}
        </Person>
      </Route>
    <Person>
  </BrowserRouter>
</RecursiveExample>
```

The person rendered at this stage happens to be `Michelle` again (because of `id` `0`).

[image: Second stage also shows friends of Michelle]

This `Person` now repeats the process. It renders its own nested `Route` that now has a `path` as `/0/:id` (because it concatenates `/:id` to the parent url) and `component` again as `Person`. Since `/0/:id` still matches `/0/1/2` (the id is now `1`), we render the next `Person`.

At this point the tree is:

```
<RecursiveExample>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Person>
      <Route path="/:id" {/* this matches /0 */}
        <Person>
          <Route path="/0/:id"> {/* this matches /0/1 */}
            <Person>
              {/* we're here during the rendering stage */}
            </Person>
          </Route>
        </Person>
      </Route>
    <Person>
  </BrowserRouter>
</RecursiveExample>
```

And the tree now shows friends of the person with `id` equal to `1`:

[image: Now we show friends of Sean]

Can you see where this is going?

This process repeats until the `path` of the `Route` rendered in the last rendered `Person` doesn't match the URL. In the case of refreshing at `/0/1/2` URL, that would be the `Route` with the `path` `/0/1/2/:id`.

This is how the final React tree looks:

```
<RecursiveExample>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Person>
      <Route path="/:id" {/* this matches /0 */}
        <Person>
          <Route path="/0/:id"> {/* this matches /0/1 */}
            <Person>
              <Route path="/0/1/:id"> {/* this matches /0/1/2 */}
                <Person>
                  <Route path="/0/1/2/:id" /> {/* this isn't matched yet */}             
                </Person>
              </Route>
            </Person>
          </Route>
        </Person>
      </Route>
    <Person>
  </BrowserRouter>
</RecursiveExample>
```

And this is the final application state:

[image: final rendered state]

---

Now, whether we actually refresh the page at `/0/1/2` or click the links to get to it, the behavior is the same.

It's important to remember that it's the URL that controls what gets rendered.

When starting the app at a particular URL via a refresh or by manually typing it, React Router goes through the nested `Person` rendering phases automatically (the first few shown above) as long as the path of each rendered route matches the URL.

On the other hand, each time we click a link to a specific URL, we manually trigger the URL change which triggers the rendering phase of the next `Person`.

Whether we manually type the URL or create it by clicking, if the resulting URL is the same, the rendered application is the same as well.
The difference is how we get to the final rendered state.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation it helped a lot!